# C# Windows forms app created using Visual Studio 2012 not working on windows xp

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have created a windows forms application using C#.net 4.0 on Visual studio 2012.
App works great on windows 8 and windows 7 but when I try to run the same app on Windows XP I get following error message.

[image]

```
Following are the prerequisites for my app:
1. .net Framework 4.0
2. Windows Installer 4.5
3. ReportViewer 2010
4. MYSQL DB 5.6
5. Visual Basic PowerPack 10
```

I have installed all these pre-requistes on Windows XP. My 1 click setup installs the application correctly but on application Start up I am receiving error.

I also tried upgrading visual studio 2012 and then rebuilding and publishing the app but still the same error persists.

Following is the screen shot from the Application Event logger

[image]

Screenshot from Project's configuration manager

[image]

Screenshot from Project Properties

[image]

Can anyone suggest me what could be the issue.

Comment: Is there any more information recorder in event log?

Comment: @Szymon I have added the screenshot from the event logger in the post

Comment: @dcastro Yes I have installed SP3 for windows xp

Comment: Dont See in configuration manager Click Build you find the option  "Platform Target" see in that ...  X64 or X86 ... change it into "AnyCpu"

Comment: @Aravind: Couldn't find "Platform Target" option in the "Build menu". Where is it located?

Comment: @NileshBarai It's on the "Build" tab underneath "Define TRACE constant"

Comment: You have Application clicked on last image right after that "Build" is there na click it... you will find Platform Target option on right side instead of Assembly Information you will get that Option

Comment: Did you check it.... ?????? What it showed in " Platform Target "

Comment: @MatthewWatson found the option. set the value to 'Any CPU' still getting the same error. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your program icon (or possibly any icons used by your program) has any images that are larger than 64x64 pixels, you can get this error on XP (in System.Drawing).

Check all your icon files and ensure that none contain images larger than 64x64

Answer (score 1):

You Need Service pack 3 for XP and check the EXE build whether it might build for X64 and also check your XP machine is having .Netframework 4.0 change that into AnyCpu and once again build 
the EXE and check with XP. and change your framework as .NetFramework 4.0

Comment: I have SP3 installed for windows XP.

Comment: Check Whether you builded your EXE in ANYCPU Mode and framework is .Netframework 4.0 , also check whether your XP machine has .NetFramework 4.0

Comment: I have added the screenshots in the original post. All the pre-requisites are exactly the same as you have mentioned. Not getting what could be the issue :(

Comment: Dont See in configuration manager Click Build you find the option "Platform Target" see in that ... X64 or X86 ... change it into "AnyCpu"

Comment: After Application Menu there you can find Build Menu .. click it you will able to see the " Platform Target"

Comment: found the option. set the value to 'Any CPU' still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Do one thing build the file and Take the whole Debug folder to XP machine .. i think dll dependencies are there .. try like this

Comment: No Luck. Still the same error. If I try running VSHost file I get not valid win32 application error

Comment: Finally got it sorted out... Thank you for all the support!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting Mixed Platforms/Any CPU/x86? Can you try different build configurations?
Are you referencing any third party DLL's?
Can you catch and log details of the exception, or does the program fail to execute entirely?

I've had strange issues before when compiling for Mixed/Any CPU, and x86 machines throw a wobbler if the program isn't specifically targetted to x86.

Comment: I even tried x86 but I got the same error. I am referencing 3rd party dlls. can that cause this issue?

Comment: Possibly - in my case it was the 3rd party dll that didn't work unless specifically targetting x86, when compiled for Mixed/Any, the 32-bit machines were trying to execute the 64-bit code.
It's unlikely that this is the same thing, but still worth a check.